# Securely transferring data to webpage

Tags: web-services, security, http, http-status-code-301

The question is related to securely transferring data to a webpage. I need to transfer some data to a webpage/website. Assume that for all the mentioned scenarios, I am using HTTPS as the protocol.

1. Do I need to append data/Parameter to URL. Do I need to encrypt it so that it does not transmit as plain text?
2. Do I make a POST request to website and it will return me the rendered HTML page?

Security is the major concern for me and I have to use HTTP or restful web services for the purpose.

Comment: Can you expand a bit on what you mean by number 1? Maybe an example? Is this for a query string? What kind of data is it?

Comment: Uhm... when you use HTTPS all traffic -- no matter whether you `GET` or `POST` to the site -- is encrypted (that's the point of HTTPS).  
So what is your question exactly?

Comment: i want to transfer text data only. is Using query string to send data is secure or there is better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Query string data will be encrypted, but it will also be visible in the browser address bar and could be logged in browser history. Even if it is a server side request, query string data could be logged in server logs.

Sending the data via POST is preferred - it is not guaranteed to not be logged, but by POSTing the data you are implying that it is used to create a change in state and that it should not be replayed or cached.